# Calculating relative surface of 3band raster image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, 3d, multi-band, surface

I am trying to calculate the (relative) area of this image. It is a scan of a tree, the colors indicate the moisture in the stem. If I load it in QGIS, I see 3 bands, the combination of which define the color. (brown is dry wood, from green it goes to purple and blue which is rotten.)

I have managed to make a tiff for each band, but how to proceed? I just need to know what percentage is brown, green, etc.

[image]

Comment: In addition, brown is where band 1 has highest value, then band 2 and 3. Green is where band 2 has highest value, then band 3 and 1. Purple is where band 1 is highest, then 3 and 2 and finally blue is where band 3 is highest, then band 2 and 1.